# Is there a way to capture a specific values between parentheses so they can be replaced

Tags: python, regex, parsing

I am trying to use REGEX in Python to parse out a document. I want to replace all instances of * that appear within parentheses. eg ("A2OR01"  *  "A2OR02"  *  "A2OR03") to ("A2OR01"  ,  "A2OR02"  ,  "A2OR03").

So far I have tried (.+  (*)  .+) but it only will match the last instance of the *. For example when I replace with the REGEX expression that I wrote I get ("A2OR01"  *  "A2OR02"  ,  "A2OR03"). I need all instances of * that are surrounded by parentheses to be replaced not just the last. I want to ignore all the values between the parentheses as they can vary including whitespaces.

Comment: if the * only appears as in your example you could just use `newstring = oldlstring.replace("*",",")`

Comment: They want to check within the parentheses, not just within the string.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code:

```
import re
s = '("A2OR01" * "A2OR02" * "A2OR03")'
res = re.findall('\(.*?\)', s) # Get all instances of strings within parantheses (list)
print(res) # ['("A2OR01" * "A2OR02" * "A2OR03")']
for i in range(len(res)):
    res[i] = res[i].replace("*",",") # Replace all instances of * within parantheses
print(res) # ['("A2OR01" , "A2OR02" , "A2OR03")']
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't bother with regex for something that's so trivial to implement without additional modules.

```
def replace_asterisks(s):
    pcount = 0
    chars = []
    for c in s:
        match c:
            case '(':
                pcount += 1
            case ')':
                pcount -= 1
            case '*':
                if pcount > 0:
                    c = ','
        chars.append(c)
    return ''.join(chars) if pcount == 0 else s

print(replace_asterisks('("A2OR01" * "A2OR02" * "A2OR03")'))
print(replace_asterisks('"A2OR01" * "A2OR02" * "A2OR03")'))
print(replace_asterisks('("A2OR01" * "A2OR02" * "A2OR03"'))
```

**Output:**

```
("A2OR01" , "A2OR02" , "A2OR03")
"A2OR01" * "A2OR02" * "A2OR03")
("A2OR01" * "A2OR02" * "A2OR03"
```